# Possible bug in reputation change alert

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, achievements-dialog

I have asked a question on SO today, and get a downvote and an upvote. I have refreshed the page several times, and opened other SO pages with my account, but the "achievements" icon was in default state. I got a medal too, and it was shown correctly (correctly means as usual).

The reputation changes no longer shown by the achievements icon, or something went wrong?

**Edit:** The amount of reputation I had was shown correctly when it changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reputation never changed in a positive direction. You received a downvote on your question, and you marked an answer as accepted. As a result, your *net* reputation change was 0 (-2 + 2).

As your reputation did not *increase*, the achievements icon does not light up.

Comment: That was clear, but in t(0) I had x reputation, in t(1) I had x-2, and in t(2) I had x-2+2=x. But I refreshed the page between the given t(i) moments. Your answer is right if there wasn't page refresh between t(0) and t(2).

Comment: @TamásJuhász: *downward* reputation changes are not seen as an achievement and are not shown either.

Comment: I see. Should I delete this question?

Comment: It's fine to leave it as is; a developer may mark it as `status-bydesign` perhaps, or perhaps there is a canonical question to dupe this to. It may help others in the future.